# Как прописать скрипт, чтобы при нажатии на стрелку, страница скроллила на следующую секцию вниз?

Tags: javascript

Какой прописать скрипт, чтобы при нажатии на стрелку вниз происходил скролл вниз? Код для верхней стрелки прописать удалось, а для нижней не знаю что

```js
$(".fa-arrow-alt-circle-up").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate( { scrollTop : 0 } ,'slow');
} );
```

Сам сайт http://ilyin1ib.beget.tech/

Весь код https://jsfiddle.net/3vnux5so/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Обращаемся к MDN за методом [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) и CSS-свойством [scroll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior)

Прописав данное css-правило, вы указываете что вся прокрутка на странице будет происходить гладко

```css
* {
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Потом выбираете элемент на странице к которому нужно скроллить, пусть это будет `div#block2`:

```js
$(".fa-arrow-alt-circle-up").click(function() {
    $('#block2')[0].scrollIntoView();
});
```

Comment: предложенный вами метод мне не очень подходит. Я вроде нашел метод, который похож на тот, что работает со стрелкой вверх, но  у меня почему-то слишком вниз уезжает страница при скроллинге.  $(".fa-arrow-alt-circle-down").click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 'slow');
    });

Comment: @Outif а что конкретно не подходит?